# file command + how to view all results from file command

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, solaris, filenames

I use the file command in order to verify if file (PATH) is text/ascii file or encrypted file

Because file command have allot of results ( small example in example 1 )
I want to get the all possibilities that we can get from file results

Please advice from where we can find the total list of file results? (relevant for linux/solaris)

Example 1

File command results ( very short list ....)

```
   ASCII text
   ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
   ASCII English text
   ASCII English text, with very long lines

   etc....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `--mime` instead of the default output. The MIME will return output like this:

```
foobar: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

The full list is typically found in the `/etc/mime.types` file.

Comment: what the add value from (--mime ) , I mean what the extra data that we get by using the ( (--mime ) ?

Comment: One question if I use the flag (--mime) and I get from file file command the output --> "text" or "text/plain", its mean the file PATH isn’t encrypted file ?

Comment: so if I get the "text/plain" then its mean that the file isnt encrypted file for sure ?

Comment: @yael No, it just means there is no binary data and no other known structure. `file` cannot detect whether the content is encrypted or not (this is generally near impossible).

Comment: for solrais (flag  --mime  ) not defined in file command , so what syntax need for solaris ?

Comment: @SCAI - so if I want to find only text/ASCII files what the best tool/command to use ? ( other alternative ? )

Comment: @yael Why do you think `file` isn't suitable for this? Just look at the charset.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:
All of the checks and returns that `file` does is located in `/usr/share/misc/magic`

There is no `file` option to "display all"

Comment: what I need is all Possibilities that file can display on the output - as you know file have allot of Possibilities - but how to know them? or listed them?

Comment: `less /usr/share/misc/magic`

Comment: Here, `/usr/share/misc/magic` is an empty directory (Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: `file --version` should report the version of `file` as well as the location of the magic file

Comment: @h3rrmiller: `man file` is more reliable to find the location of the magic file, Solaris & AIX `file` don't have a `--version` switch for instance :)

Comment: @Mat you are correct.  I always forget to include the Solaris way of doing things :P

Comment: @h3rrmiller Just for the record, here it uses the *compiled* file */usr/share/misc/magic.mgc* which cannot be displayed with a simple text editor.

Comment: @scai That's strange.  Every system I have (RHEL6, Gentoo, Sol10) has both a compiled `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc` and a text file called `/usr/share/misc/magic`.  Must be non-default though.